# vb.net copy file to folder (80 files per folder)

Tags: .net, vb.net

there is a folder named "X"
"X" folder has around 100-1000 files in there
example file name: 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg ---> 1000.jpg

first, i want to count them how much file in there

if there is 160 files then, create 2 folder (named 1 and 2)
move 1.jpg-80.jpg file to folder 1 (total: 80)
move 81.jpg-160.jpg file to folder 2 (total: 80)

but if there is 200 files then, create 3 folder (named 1, 2 and 3)
move 1.jpg-80.jpg file to folder 1 (total: 80)
move 81.jpg-160.jpg file to folder 2( total: 80)
move 161.jpg-200.jpg file to folder 3 (total: 40)

Comment: Do you want to create the folders (1..x) as subolders of "X"?

Comment: @tpol that's right sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this approach. Cycle over the files in your folder X using Directory.EnumerateFile and count. When the result of the mod 80 operation returns zero you are reaty to create a new subfolder and restart the count of files.

```
Dim dirCount = 0
Dim fileCount = 0
Dim totalFileCount = 0

Dim x As String = "e:\temp"
Dim newFolder As String = ""

 ' Get one file name at time
For Each file In Directory.EnumerateFiles(x, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    ' Do we need to create a new folder?
    ' This is true even when fileCount is zero
    If fileCount Mod 80 = 0 Then
        dirCount += 1
        newFolder = Path.Combine(x, dirCount.ToString())
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder.ToString())
        fileCount = 0
    End If
    Dim newFile = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(newFolder), Path.GetFileName(file))
    System.IO.File.Move(file, newFile)
    fileCount += 1
    totalFileCount += 1
Next
Console.WriteLine("Moved " & totalFileCount  + " files")
```

Comment: i try your code but it's unsorted file, in folder 1 should be 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg but your code is doing 1.jpg 80.jpg 81.jpg and got a warning "Variable 'newFolder' is used before it has been assigned a value"

Comment: problem solved! i change file name to 00000x.jpg e.g. 000001.jpg 000002.jpg // your code is working fine sir thanks